# creating a new linear layout

Tags: java, android

i created button and other...
but now when i want to create a three buttons green,red,blue they are not showing up i want them to be directly down the button1 but they are not showing up i wish you can help me this is the error im getting -xml documents must start and end within the same entity the error is showing in the last last last linearlayout

this is the code im having problem with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Greetings"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


</RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="red" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fourthLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="green" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifthLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="blue" />

     <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


</RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

this is a picture for the red blue green buttons where to be while mine are down
https://www.dropbox.com/s/73grdc0iff3ql3u/Untitled.png

this is what i reached to till now but i want them to be equally distributed like the picture above
https://www.dropbox.com/s/73grdc0iff3ql3u/Untitled.png

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: Can you post your desired screen shot which type of layout do you want?

Comment: i want it to be like the one in this pic i have the button and the word working only the buttons are down while i need them like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/73grdc0iff3ql3u/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

You need one more `</LinearLayout>` at the end of your xml file. At the minute, only 2 of the 3 `LinearLayout`'s are being closed.

**EDIT**
The reason your Buttons are appearing at the bottom is because of this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure what purpose this serves in your application, but removing that will fix your problem.

Comment: it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you have not closed the below linear layout tag in your xml.
    "<"LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" ">"

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xml with following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HelloWord" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.3"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="red"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fourthLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.4"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:text="green"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fifthLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.3"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:text="blue"
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.